# How to enable the pyd to call functions in external C++ dll?

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm trying to design an external `DLL` for my python program. Now I could use the *C++* and *Visual Studio 2010* to produce a file with a postfix of `".pyd"`. If the `.pyd` is not attached with other `.dll` files produced by C++, this python library could work well.

However, now I need to design a `.pyd` file with such a struction:

`A.pyd  -> 1.dll
        -> 2.dll`

in which the files 1,2 are C libraries. The functions in these libraries are called when producing `A.pyd`.

Although this `.pyd` file could be produced without errors by *VS 2010*, it could not work in python 3.6. The error report is as follow:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: DLL load failed, could not find the target program.`

Even when the referred `1.dll` and `2.dll` are stored in **the same folder that contains `A.pyd`**, this error still exists. I wonder **how could I enable the *python-C++* library to call the functions in these dynamic link libraries based on `C`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Now I have found the correct way to perform this operation!

## Wrap the DLL

At first, if the dll **(I call it `dll-A`)** that you need to call has not exported any function (you could use `dumpbin` in VS command to check the exported functions), you need to wrap the original `dll-A`. Use the implicit call to include `dll-A`. If there is a function declared in the original .h/.lib, like this:

```
int func(int a, int b);
```

Then you need to create a new dll project and wrap the above function by this:

.h

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int w_func(int a, int b);
```

.cpp

```
int w_func(int a, int b){
    return func(a, b);
}
```

Certainly, if the `dumpbin` shows that `dll-A` have avaliable exported functions, you could skip this step.

After exporting this dll **(I call it `dll-B`)**, you will get 'dll-B' and its depending files (including `dll-A` and `dll-A`'s depending files).

## Write the .pyd file

Use the explicit call to refer `dll-B`. When using this method, you should not include any lib/.h files, because `dll-B` itself could provide you with enough interfaces. You could load the dll by this method:

.h

```
typedef int (*func_ptr)(int a, int b);
```

.cpp (part of a function named `Testdll` when you write the .pyd project)

```
func_ptr FUNC_API = NULL;
HINSTANCE h = LoadLibraryA("libdll/dllB.dll"); 
//Certainly! you could set the folder of stored dlls!
if (h){
    FUNC_API = (func_ptr)GetProcAddress(h, "w_func");
    //You could load more functions here.
}
else{ // If the dll could not be found
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0x100;
}
int errorflag=0;
if (FUNC_API==NULL){ //Check whether the function is valid.
    cout << "Could not find: func" << endl;
    errorflag = errorflag | 0x001;
}
//You could check more functions here.
if (errorflag!=0){ // if any function could not be found.
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0x100 | errorflag;
}
//process functions.
int a,b,c;
c = FUNC_API(a,b);
//Free the lib
if (h)
    FreeLibrary(h);
```

After build your own .pyd, you could get your python database **(I call it `pyd-C`)**.

## Link the .pyd with Python

In python project, you could test this file by this method:

.py

```
import pydC

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = pydC.cclass()
    X.Testdll();
```

Then you can find that the function is performed well.

Noted that your .pyd should be in the same folder with where .py is. Because you have set `dll-B` in `libdll/dllB.dll`, `dll-B` should be put in the folder named `libdll`. However, because `dll-B` calls `dll-A` and other depending dlls implicitly, `dll-A` and other files should be in your workspace folder, i.e. the same folder with where .py is.

In short, you need to enter the workspace folder, and the folder formation is as follow:

```
./
    Test.py
    pydC.pyd
    dllA.dll
    dllA_depended1.dll
    ...
    libdll/
        dllB.dll
```

Comment: If any of your refered dll is written badly, you may meet critical errors! This is unfortunately because you may not be able to refine those depending dlls. Generally,  you could write a C program to refer the exported dll explicitly to test whether it is OK to run those dlls. If the .exe throws an error, it is almost inevitable to meet the same error in your .py.